# What's the most efficient way to store sets in a database?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, set, relational-database

I want to store sets in a such a way that I can query for sets that are a superset of, subset of, or intersect with another set.

For example, if my database has the sets { 1, 2, 3 }, { 2, 3, 5 }, { 5, 10, 12} and I query it for:

- Sets which are supersets of { 2, 3 } it should give me { 1, 2, 3 }, { 2, 3, 5 }
- Sets which are subsets of { 1, 2, 3, 4 } it should give me { 1, 2, 3 }
- Sets which intersect with { 1, 10, 20 } it should give me { 1, 2, 3 }, { 5, 10, 12}

Comment: Example data would help

Comment: Please add that well formatted to your question. Thank you.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? Btw: SQL has an `intersect`, `except` an `in` operator

Comment: I'm using SQLite but I was hoping for a generic answer.

Comment: When you say: _"Sets which are supersets of { 2, 3 }"_, is { 2, 3 } already present in the database, or is it given as a search criteria by the client?

Comment: It is given as a search criteria. Is it possible to do both?

Comment: @mtanti I'm not sure I understand the question. It is possible to search based on data that comes from the outside and it is possible to search based on data that is already in the database, but which of these two makes sense (or both?) is part of your requirements gathering.

Comment: In the situation I would need it, it would be given as a search criteria from the outside. But I'm wondering if it's possible to keep the structure generic enough to, say, find the set which intersects with most sets in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Since some sets are unknown in advance (your comment suggests they come from the client as a search criteria), you cannot "precook" the set relationships into the database. Even if you could, that would represent a redundancy and therefore an opportunity for inconsistencies.

Instead, I'd do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "SET" (
    ELEMENT INT, -- Or whatever the element type is.
    SET_ID INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ELEMENT, SET_ID)
)
```

Additional suggestions:

- Note how ELEMENT field is at the primary key's leading edge. This should aid the queries below better than PRIMARY KEY (SET_ID, ELEMENT). You can still add the latter if desired, but if you don't, then you should also...
- [**Cluster**](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index) the table (if your DBMS supports it), which means that the whole table is just a single B-Tree (and no table heap). That way, you maximize the performance of queries below, and minimize storage requirements (and cache effectiveness).

You can then find IDs of sets that are equal to or supersets of (for example) set {2, 3} like this:

```
SELECT SET_ID
FROM "SET"
WHERE ELEMENT IN (2, 3)
GROUP BY SET_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

And sets that intersect {2, 3} like this:

```
SELECT SET_ID
FROM "SET"
WHERE ELEMENT IN (2, 3)
GROUP BY SET_ID;
```

And sets that are equal to or are subsets of {2, 3} like this:

```
SELECT SET_ID
FROM "SET"
WHERE SET_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT SET_ID
    FROM "SET" S2
    WHERE S2.ELEMENT NOT IN (2, 3)
)
GROUP BY SET_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

"Efficient" can mean a lot of things, but the normalized way would be to have an Items table with all the possible elements and a Sets table with all the sets, and an ItemsSets lookup table. If you have sets A and B in your Sets table, queries like (doing this for clarity rather than optimization... also "Set" is a bad name for a table or field, given it is a keyword)

```
SELECT itemname FROM Items i 
WHERE i.itemname IN 
 (SELECT itemname FROM ItemsSets isets WHERE isets.setname = 'A') 
AND i.name IN 
 (SELECT itemname FROM ItemsSets isets WHERE isets.setname = 'B')
```

That, for instance, is the intersection of A and B (you can almost certainly speed this up as a JOIN; again, "efficient" can mean a lot of things, and you'll want an architecture that allows a query like that). Similar queries can be made to find out the difference, complement, test for equality, etc.

Now, I know you asked about efficiency, and this is a horribly slow way to query, but this is the only reliably scalable *architecture* for the tables to do this, and the query was just an easy one to show how the tables are built. You can do all sorts of crazy things to, say, cache intersections, or store multiple items that are in a set in one field and process that, or what have you. But don't. Cached info will eventually get stale; static limits on the number of items in the field size will be surpassed; ad-hoc members of new tuples will be misinterpreted.

Again, "efficient" can mean a lot of different things, but ultimately an information architecture you as a programmer can understand and reason about is going to be the most efficient.